# return multiple data to another screen flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, screen

I'm struggling to return different data to my homescreen. I have the Mypage() screen where cards in a listview are displayed with a title, and a text. I'm new to flutter and I don't really know how to return the data from my other screen named WritingPage() where there are two textfields. Here's my actual code for the button on Mypage():

```
FlatButton(
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context){
                  return WritingPage();
                })).then((value) {
              dreams.add(value);
              print(dreams);
              setState(() {});
            })
            ;
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.add, size: 30,),
          color: Colors.black,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
        ),
```

Then, here's the code of the WritingPage():

```
class WritingPage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_WritingPageState createState() => _WritingPageState();
}

class _WritingPageState extends State<WritingPage> {
String text;

void submit(){
Navigator.of(context).pop(_textEditingController.text);
}

TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController _titleEditingController = TextEditingController();
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: kEdgeColor,
    title: Text('Writing part'),
  ),
  body: Container(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          controller: _textEditingController,
          obscureText: false,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(12))
            )
          ),
        ),
        TextField(
          controller: _titleEditingController,
          obscureText: false,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(12))
              )
          ),
        ),
        RaisedButton(onPressed : ()=> submit()),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

I'd like that every time I press the button in the WritingPage, a card is created in the listview with the data of the two textfields.

If you need any more details please ask me, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In MyPage

```
FlatButton(
    onPressed: () async {
      final result = await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){return WritingPage();})); 
      if (null != result) {
        dreams.add(result);
        print(dreams);
        setState(() {});
      }
    },
    child: Icon(Icons.add, size: 30,),
    color: Colors.black,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
),
```

In WritingPage

```
void submit() {
    Navigator.of(context).pop({
      "text": _textEditingController.text.trim(),
      "title": _titleEditingController.text.trim();
    });
}
```

Comment: I got an error but I think its because dreams is a list and not a map. Well I don't know what to use to save the title and the content and then use them in a card in the listview. Here's the error :                                                                                        type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: What is the content type of variable `dreams` ?

Comment: static List dreams = [];

Comment: Where you are using `dreams` in your Card widget ?

Comment: Well that's my card constructor but I don't really know how to use it :                   class DreamCard extends StatelessWidget {
  DreamCard({this.Content, this.title});
  
  final String title;
  final String Content;

Answer (score 0):

One solution for this is to define a class in another file and then you can refer to that class from multiple pages, just remember to use setState. Also if you are popping context then make sure to rebuild the original page when returning.